# How to set GeoJSON object property as class name other than name in HighMaps

Tags: highcharts

Usually HighMap uses name value to set SVG path class name.

[image]

Is there any way to use custom property other than name property to set class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add custom class name by `className` property:

```
var data = [
    ...,
    ['DE.TH', 704, 'myCustomClassName']
];

Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    ...,

    series: [{
        data: data,
        keys: ['code_hasc', 'value', 'className'],
        ...
    }]
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vojLzdsa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.keys

Class name `'highcharts-name-...'` is default and you can remove it from an element after creating the chart or you can edit the related source code:

https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts-map/MapSeries.js#L827

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts